# why mandelbrot's boundary is 2?

Tags: fractals, mandelbrot

I'm trying to understand why we're iterating through Mandelbrot points until |z| < 4.
why 4? is there somekind of a law? or is it based on statistical measurements?

thanks, igal

Comment: This seems like more of a math question than a programming question. The [wikipedia entry on Mandelbrot sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) explains it mathematically. In short - the entire set is contained within a circle of radius 2. If your calculation gets larger than that, the orbit of that point is headed to infinity, and is not part of the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Mandelbrot set with along y=0, which would would be `z(i) = z(i-1)^2 + c`.

Consider when `c = (x=-2, y=0)`

```
z(0) = 0
z(1) = 0^2 + -2 = -2
z(2) = (-2)^2 + -2 = 4 - 2 = 2
z(3) = 2^2 + -2 = 4 - 2 = 2
z(...) = 2^2 + -2 = 4 - 2 = 2
```

This example (`x=-2,y=0`) is the point with the greatest magnitude that will never blow up.  Thus when `z^2 > 4`, there is no point in further iteration since you already know it will blow up.

All other points where the magnitude of the point >= 2 will blow up.