# I can't understantd something about mandelbrot fractal code

Tags: java, javascript, fractals, mandelbrot

It is calculation function code.
I heard "escape" should be `4(2^2)`.
because if (`z_r*z_r + z_i*z_i`) is smaller than `4` it won't go infinity.
but in this code escape is `1025^2`. why ? why `1025^2`?

```
function computeRow(task) {
var iter = 0; //iteration
var c_i = task.i; //
var max_iter = task.max_iter; // = 1024
var escape = task.escape * task.escape; //task.escape=1025
task.values = [];
for(var i = 0; i <task.width;i++) {
    var c_r = task.r_min+(task.r_max - task.r_min) * i/ task.width;
    var z_r = 0, z_i = 0;

    for(iter = 0; z_r*z_r + z_i*z_i < escape && iter < max_iter; iter++) {
        // z->z^2 + c                   ▲ i wonder about this
        var tmp = z_r*z_r - z_i*z_i + c_r;
        z_i = 2*z_r*z_i+c_i;
        z_r = tmp;
    }
    if(iter == max_iter) {
        iter = -1;
    }
    task.values.push(iter);
}
return task;}
```

Comment: Escape should be 2, but you need to understand first the calculation basics. I have written an summary of the most important parts here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253208/having-trouble-calculating-mandelbrot-set-iterations/9941874#9941874

Comment: Is this your own code? Just because you are asking questions about it. You use the "task" object as argument, but there is no info about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I heard "escape" should be 4(2^2)

[Escape radius should be greater then 2](http://mrob.com/pub/muency/escaperadius.html) 
so any value > 2 is good. It can change shape of level sets and shape of numerical aproximation of Mandelbrot set. Square of escape radius should be greater then 4.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690224/why-mandelbrots-boundary-is-2)

HTH